# Check if folder can be deleted

Tags: vba

I'm working on a script that will delete files & folders after a certain age and will create a log about the action.

```
For Each oFile In fso.GetFolder(C.Value).Files
    
    If DateDiff("h", GetFileAge(oFile.Path), Now) > DelAfterH Then
        If IsFileWriteable(oFile.Path) Then
            Call LogResults(oFile.Path, "File deleted!")
            Logged = True
            Kill oFile
        Else
            Call LogResults(oFile.Path, "File protected!")
            Logged = True
        End If
        
    End If
    
Next oFile
```

A possible issue that can appear is when a file is opened at someone and becomes write protected, so the script should just skip it.
I can easily verify this with a function I found:

```
Function IsFileWriteable(strFile As String) As Boolean

Dim i As Integer
i = FreeFile
On Error Resume Next
Open strFile For Binary Access Write As #i
Close #i
IsFileWriteable = (Err = 0)

End Function
```

Folders are a different story however. Whenever someone has a file opened in the folder, the script will just halt with *Run-time error '75'*.
Also the same function can not be used in this case.

Is there a way to test the folder with a similar method before trying to delete?
Or I'm just stuck with error handling?

Comment: It might seem more elegant to avoid brute force but sometimes testing under an error handler is both the simplest and most efficient way. In this context think of the error as reporting back not-successful!

Comment: I agree with @PeterT.  And notice that `IsFileWriteable` also uses this error handling technique.

Answer (score 1):

You can offload the delete operation to a helper function that returns true if the file/folder was deleted and false if not.

The function itself suspends error reporting, tries to delete the file and returns a boolean based on the error number. If zero, no error raised.

```
Private Function TryToDelete(ByVal path As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill path
    TryToDelete = Err.Number = 0 'if failed, it would be > 0, i.e. 75
End Function
```

---

```
For Each oFile In fso.GetFolder(C.Value).Files
    
    If DateDiff("h", GetFileAge(oFile.Path), Now) > DelAfterH Then
        If TryToDelete(oFile.Path) Then
            Call LogResults(oFile.Path, "Deleted!")
        Else
            Call LogResults(oFile.Path, "Could not delete.")
        End If
        Logged = True
    End if
Next oFile
```